# Professor stopped replying after showing interest in introductory email

Tags: masters, application, japan

I want to do my Master's Degree from Japan, for which I sent an email with my research proposal on 3rd August, 2022. The Professor replied within 2 hours of email, showing interest in my profile and asking for funds, to which I responded positively (will be able to manage funds). It has been 10 days and I have not received any procedure for interview. Should I send a follow up email? Is there any holidays period in the University? How much time should I wait before directly calling the professor?

Answer (score 2):

If you need advice on how to apply, consider emailing professor with this very explicit question. The professor does not know that you do not know how to apply. From their perspective, a student inquired about a possibility to do a PhD with them and received a positive response (subject to funds), student then confirmed the funds available --- all good, no further action required.

Answer (score 0):

Sending him a reminder after about a week is certainly okay. Make sure to be polite and do not blame him for not answering. Re-express your interest and emphasise again that you have funding available.